# Scala - find maximum and sum of values in list of custom objects

Tags: scala

I have a simple case class:

```
case class Task (
  val name: String,
  val value: Option[Int],
  val description: String
)
```

I have a list of these objects, where same `name` could be multiple times. I would like to find maximum `value` of same objects with same `name` and sum these values.

But I have a problem because I am not sure how to find a maximum of `Options` values. What if they are None?
What would be the simplest way to do it? I tried something like:

```
val max = list.filter(_.name == "Homework").reduceLeft(_.value max _.value).get
```

but it did not work, because if some `value` is None, then I got error.

Comment: Use `groupMap` to get all the values of the same key, then `view.mapValues` to access each list, a d I am pretty sure there is a default ordering for options where `None` is always less than anything else, so you can just call `max` on those lists and the call `sum` on the values.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Scala 2.13.x then you can use `groupMapReduce()`.

```
val maxAndSumByName: Map[String,(Int,Int)] =
  tasks.groupMapReduce(_.name
                      )(_.value.fold(Int.MinValue,0)(n=>(n,n))
                       ){case ((ax,as),(bx,bs)) =>
                          (ax max bx, as+bs)
                        }
```

The 1st `Int` in the tuple is the maximum and the 2nd `Int` is the sum.

Comment: But I need to do it for every "name", not only "Homework". It was an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you have some tasks in the list which occur once and have the value None, there is no max value for the entry. So, it makes sense if we represent the max value as Option[Int]. The solution I came up with is,

```
val nameMaxMap: Map[String, (Option[Int], Int)] =
    tasks.groupBy(t => t.name)
        .map(entry => (
            entry._1,
            entry._2.foldLeft((Option.empty[Int], 0)) {
            case ((None, sum), Task(_, None, _)) => (None, sum)
            case ((None, sum), Task(_, Some(value), _)) => (Some(value), sum + value)
            case ((Some(soFarMax), sum), Task(_, None, _)) => (Some(soFarMax), sum)
            case ((Some(soFarMax), sum), Task(_, Some(value), _)) => (Some(value max soFarMax), sum + value)
        }))
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, the stdlib provides a default ordering for optional values as long as the type inside the option is orderable.

Thus, you can solve this problem very easily using `groupMap` to produce a **Map** from the task names to all their values and then picking the `max` from each of those groups and finally summing together all those maximus.

```scala
def sumByMax(data: List[Task]): Int =
  data
    .groupMap(_.name)(_.value)
    .valuesIterator
    .map(_.max.getOrElse(0))
    .sum
```

---

*Code running in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/hqjomZ42S7u0oguhNhpKhA/4)*.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, grouping is a very handy tool:

Assuming I have a list of tasks called `tasks`, we can group them by name like so:

```scala
    val tasksGroupedByName: Map[String, List[Task]] = tasks.groupBy(_.name)
```

To calculate the sum, for each name (or using 0 as the default value [i.e. an empty list]) we can also use some built in functions:

```scala
    val sums: Map[String, Int] = tasksGroupedByName.map {
        case nameToTaskMap: (String, List[Task]) =>
            // Destructure to get the name and the taskList (each map entry)
            val (name, taskList) = nameToTaskMap
            // Use map to get only the value, and use flatten to get only the Ints
            val valueList: List[Int] = taskList.map(_.value).flatten
            // We're not reinventing the wheel here
            val sum: Int = valueList.sum
            (name, sum)
    }
```

We can use similar logic to compute the maximum value. Others have provided some good solutions, but I wanted to share another possibility.

If we remove the `Option`, this becomes far simpler to compute. As seen above, we can do this fairly simply using `flatten` on a list of `Option`s, which will yield a `List` of the type contained in the `Option`, in this case `Int`.

```scala
    def maxValue(valueList: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
        valueList match {
                // BASE CASE: Empty list
            case Nil => None
                // BASE CASE: Single value
            case singleValue :: Nil => Some(singleValue)
                // First value is larger than second value
                // Repeat, but remove second value (Size: n - 1)
            case firstValue :: secondValue :: tailValues if firstValue > secondValue =>
                    maxValue(firstValue :: tailValues)
                // First value is NOT larger than second value
                // Repeat, but without first value (Size: n - 1)
            case _ :: tailValues => maxValue(tailValues)
        }
    }

    val maxValues: Map[String, Option[Int]] = tasksGroupedByName.map{
        case nameToTaskMap: (String, List[Task]) => 
            val (name, taskList) = nameToTaskMap
            val valueList: List[Int] = taskList.map(_.value).flatten
            val maxVal: Option[Int] = maxValue(valueList)
            (name, maxVal)
    }
```

Side Note: Recursion is NOT necessary here, as we could use `List.max` as soon as we have a list of `Int`s. However, if the type were more complex, this kind of pattern could apply very handily, plus I just think it's neat.